# Passing parameters from batch to vba and get output value back in batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, qtp

I'm making a utility using QuickTest Professional which calls a batch file with some parameters.

This batch file further calls a vbscript and passes some parameters to this vbs file.

This vbs file perform operations and generate a number.

I want this number to flow back from vbs to batch and then to QTP.

This is what I've figured out so far:

```
  QTP(sending parameters to bat)  >>   Batch(sending parameters to vbs)   >>  VBS (generates a number)
```

now I want this vbs to return the output number back

```
  VBS   >>  Batch(same bat which called vbs file)   >>  QTP(same qtp process which called this batch)
```

Here is my code:

QTP: (calling batch)

```
   Dim BatchRun
   Set BatchRun = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
   invokefile= Chr(34) + "C:/invokebugz.bat" + Chr(34) 
   BatchRun.Run invokebugzfile & lob & " " &  mailto & " " & mailcc & " " &  title  & " " &   subject
```

Bat: (calling vbs)

```
   cd C:\
   cscript abc.vbs "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "%~5"
```

vbs:

```
 Set args = Wscript.Arguments ' to accept command line arguments
 xprod = args(0)
 mailto = args(1)
 mailcc = args(2)
 xtitle = args(3)
 xcomment = args(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value back if you just print it to standard output.  So just write the result from VBS like this:

```
Wscript.Echo result
```

The `for` command can be used to get the output of a command that you invoke:

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript abc.vbs "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "%~5"') do (
    echo The output is %%a
)
```

If the output is just a number, you shouldn't need to add any extra options to the for loop.  Try running `for /?` for more help.